# How to check that a string is parseable to a double?

Tags: java, string, parsing, floating-point

Is there a native way (preferably without implementing your own method) to check that a string is parseable with `Double.parseDouble()`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The common approach would be to check it with a regular expression like it's also suggested inside the [`Double.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) documentation.

The regexp provided there (or included below) should cover all valid floating point cases, so you don't need to fiddle with it, since you will eventually miss out on some of the finer points.

If you don't want to do that, `try catch` is still an option.

The regexp suggested by the JavaDoc is included below:

```
final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
// an exponent is 'e' or 'E' followed by an optionally 
// signed decimal integer.
final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
final String fpRegex    =
    ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+ // Optional leading "whitespace"
    "[+-]?(" +         // Optional sign character
    "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
    "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string

    // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
    // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
    // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
    // 
    // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
    // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
    // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
    // productions from the Java Language Specification, 2nd 
    // edition, section 3.10.2.

    // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
    "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+

    // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
    "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+

    // Hexadecimal strings
    "((" +
    // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
    "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +

    // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
    "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +

    ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
    "[fFdD]?))" +
    "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"

if (Pattern.matches(fpRegex, myString)){
    Double.valueOf(myString); // Will not throw NumberFormatException
} else {
    // Perform suitable alternative action
}
```

Comment: +1 - Much better than catching an exception (my lame answer...)

Comment: how does one do this exactly?

Comment: @Louis Rhys - There is a code example in the documentation link in the answer.

Comment: @Louis Rhys: The complete code you need is provided in behind the link. You just need to copy that into your code and wrap the final if statement around your use of `Double.parseDouble`. But I would put the could into a utility class or method so it's easier reusable in your project. Something like `parseDoubleSafe(String check, Double default)` or something like that.

Comment: the approach taken by the Java API developer is imbecile: they gives us a chunk of code that every interested person has to copy/paste into a utility method. Why not just providing that method themselves in the `Double` class? :facepalm (endless)

Answer (score 73):

`Apache`, as usual, has a good answer from [`Apache Commons-Lang`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang) in the form of 
[`NumberUtils.isCreatable(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-).

Handles `null`s, no `try`/`catch` block required.

Comment: does Apache ship with the normal JDK?

Comment: No.  You can find the Apache Commons libraries here.  http://commons.apache.org/  Highly recommended that you use them rather than writing custom code whenever you can.

Comment: Does this identify decimal numbers ?

Comment: It returns false for float/double numbers.

Comment: This one does not work for certain numbers. For instance "3L". Use the accepted answer instead. For a quick example see https://gist.github.com/nachtfisch/945e3df75d70b10de99d

Comment: Using `commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils, it returns `true` for input strings `1`, `-1.23e5` or  `5L`.  It looks fine

Comment: `NumberUtils.isNumber(String)` has been deprecated, you should now use `NumberUtils.isCreatable(String)` instead.

Comment: The question is about a double, while this would return true for any kind of number, which isn't necessarily a double.

Comment: All numbers are doubles, so if it passes the number test, it will pass the double test.

Answer (score 70):

You can always wrap Double.parseDouble() in a try catch block.

```
try
{
  Double.parseDouble(number);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  //not a double
}
```

Comment: This would be my preferred method because your guaranteed to get exactly the same behavior as the parse.  It's very easy with a custom regular expression to overlook edge cases.

Comment: This is good EXCEPT if you type in a number followed by a space, it doesn't catch it.

Comment: @giant91 - just trim the number: `number.trim()`.

Comment: @giant91 So? The string is parseable, which is the actual question.

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer. This is guaranteed to work in all future versions of Java, whereas using RegEx tries to be smart and anticipate parser behavior.  Regex are very slow anyway, it's not like trying to find out the string is suitable will save you much time over simply trying to parse it and going through the exception-catching process.

Comment: @giant91 don't need to trim. Method parseDouble trims String internally.

Answer (score 11):

Something like below should suffice :-

```
String decimalPattern = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)";  
String number="20.00";  
boolean match = Pattern.matches(decimalPattern, number);
System.out.println(match); //if true then decimal else not
```

Comment: actually it's more complicated than that. see johannes wachter's answer

Comment: Got it. The link that Wachter provided is helpful indeed.

Comment: Hi, this is more proper for doubles: String doublePattern = "([0-9].*)\\.([0-9].*)";

Comment: I find this answer very good. It is much more flexible than the others and man is not dependent on a third party library.

Comment: Late to the party, but this also matches a dot as a valid double, while it would not match "20" as valid, which it actually is.

Answer (score 11):

Google's Guava library provides a nice helper method to do this: [`Doubles.tryParse(String)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)). You use it like `Double.parseDouble` but it returns `null` rather than throwing an exception if the string does not parse to a double.

Answer (score 9):

All answers are OK, depending on how academic you want to be.
If you wish to follow the Java specifications accurately, use the following:

```
private static final Pattern DOUBLE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
    "[\\x00-\\x20]*[+-]?(NaN|Infinity|((((\\p{Digit}+)(\\.)?((\\p{Digit}+)?)" +
    "([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(\\.((\\p{Digit}+))([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|" +
    "(((0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)(\\.)?)|(0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)?(\\.)(\\p{XDigit}+)))" +
    "[pP][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+)))[fFdD]?))[\\x00-\\x20]*");

public static boolean isFloat(String s)
{
    return DOUBLE_PATTERN.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

This code is based on the JavaDocs at [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Recommended answer, thanks