# Testing a string for numeric characters

Tags: java, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: how to check that a string is parsable to a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543729/java-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-parsable-to-a-double)

What is the best way to check a string for numeric characters in Java?

```
    try {
        NumberFormat defForm = NumberFormat.getInstance();            
        Number n = defForm.parse(s);      
        double d = n.doubleValue();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Do something here...    
    }
```

Or is there a better way using REGEX?

I don't want to strip the numbers.

Comment: are you saying string like `"56"` or also `"aaa56aaa"`?

Comment: yes you can use Regex and do a pattern recognition..

Comment: Also, which kinds of numbers would you want to allow? I'm thinking `1e4` - is that a valid number for you? How about `NaN` or `-Inf`?

Comment: Scanner can, also parse different numbers in a line

Comment: The string could be "56" or "aaa56aaa". Can anyone suggest a regex?

Comment: A regex to do what exactly? Find any embedded number? Find out *if* there is any embedded number?

Comment: Also, to the close-voters: This is not a duplicate of said question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regex u can do it this way -

```
String s="aa56aa";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String test = "12cats";
//String test = "catscats";
//String test = "c4ts";
//String test = "12345";
if (test.matches(".*[0-9].*") {
    System.out.println("Contains numbers");
} else {
    System.out.println("Does not contain numbers");
} //End if
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to use a `regex` ([link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)  <- here you have everything you need to work wih regexes).

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question (vague as it is).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But sincerely, the question is of a "lmgtfy" category

Comment: In case you don't know: "lmgtfy" stands for "Let Me Google That For You" :)

Comment: I do know this, and you might like to know that answers of this kind are considered rude on StackOverflow and are likely to get downvoted and/or deleted.

Comment: Thanks again for pointing that out, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Return true if your string contains a number,
 * false otherwise.
 */
str.matches("\\d+");
```

e.g.:

```
"csvw10vsdvsv".matches("\\d+"); // true
"aaa".matches("\\d+"); // false
```

Comment: Get an illegal character \92 char message here. Any ideas?

Comment: @MrMorgan: Sorry. I mixed javascript with Java. I changed my solution. Take a look!