# how to check if user input is a double?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my JSP page, I let users input their dollar balance.
Then I catch this in servlet as: `String input = req.getParameter("balance");`

How do I check if `input` variable is double? I know how to use `ParseDouble`, but I don't want to catch the exception. Instead, I want to pass my own error message to JSP so that users can see it when they have typing error.

Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how to check that a string is parsable to a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543729/java-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-parsable-to-a-double)

Comment: Catch the NumberFormatException, and rethrow your own 'MyJspUserException'.

Answer (score 4):

You may also create a function like this:

```
boolean isDouble(String input) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(input);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //You can send the message which you want to show to your users here.
            return false;
        }
    }
```