# Check if a string value is equal to a double?

Tags: java, variables, performance

I have multiple strings that may or may not be equal to a double value (e.g. "444", "44.4", "-0.0044").  I was wondering what the most efficient way would be to check if it is equal to a double.  At first I was using a try-catch statement but other posts on StackOverflow have said that those are costly to performance if an exception is thrown. Here is the code I have so far:

```
try { 
     double a = Double.parseDouble("444");
     return true;
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543729/java-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-parsable-to-a-double

Comment: Since you do not have a method, you can not simply add return statements. Instead you could do this try {
  d = Double.parseDouble(string);
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // do something here
}

Comment: @NikosMargaritis but they want to avoid throwing the Exception in the first place

Comment: @JavaDevil then he should test the string over a specified pattern before parsing it.

Comment: @NikosMargaritis Which is exactly the kind of answer they were looking for... not the same code again.

Comment: @JavaDevil somebody gave the answer already, however, the reason I made the comment in the first place is related with the fact of the return statements and not with the answer. That's why I comment and didnt answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java specifies a regular expression that can be used to validate strings being passed to `Double.parseDouble` or `Double.valueOf` in the Javadoc of [`Double.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

```
final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
// an exponent is 'e' or 'E' followed by an optionally
// signed decimal integer.
final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
final String fpRegex    =
  ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+  // Optional leading "whitespace"
   "[+-]?(" + // Optional sign character
   "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
   "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string

   // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
   // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
   // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
   //
   // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
   // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
   // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
   // productions from section 3.10.2 of
   // The Java™ Language Specification.

   // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
   "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+

   // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
   "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+

   // Hexadecimal strings
   "((" +
    // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
    "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +

    // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
    "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +

    ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
   "[fFdD]?))" +
   "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"

 if (Pattern.matches(fpRegex, myString))
   Double.valueOf(myString); // Will not throw NumberFormatException
 else {
   // Perform suitable alternative action
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If (as the title suggests) you are testing that a `String` equals a *particular* `double`, the simplest and fastest way is to convert the double to a String and then compare:

```
if (Double.toString(d).equals(s))
```

rather than dealing with the vagaries and exceptions of parsing a string.

---

If as your code suggests, you are testing if a `String` could be *parsed* (as *any* `double`), the code you have now is probably the best way to go. Parsing floating point numbers is quite complex and the work must be done *somewhere* - might as well let the API do the work. Also, throwing an exception is not *that* expensive.

Only seek to optimize for performance if your current working implementation is proven to be too slow to be tolerable. Unless you are parsing hundreds of these per second, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: By my reading, the OP is looking to see if a String is equal to *any* double, rather than if it's equal to a *specific* double. (That confused me, too.)

Comment: @ruakh oh... I think you're right. So he means "can be parsed as any double"

Answer (score 0):

Past answers to this question say to use a pre-compiled RegEx using the pattern from the API docs

```
Pattern redbl=Pattern.compile("[\\x00-\\x20]*[+-]?(((((\\p{Digit}+)(\\.)?((\\p{Digit}+)?)([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(\\.((\\p{Digit}+))([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(((0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)(\\.)?)|(0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)?(\\.)(\\p{XDigit}+)))[pP][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+)))[fFdD]?))[\\x00-\\x20]*");
Boolean isDouble=redbl.matcher("444.123").matches();
```