# How to prevent user from entering white space or just hitting enter when a number is expected?

Tags: java

I'm trying to only accept numbers from a user. This code works for giving them an error message if they enter a letter. But it doesn't work for if they hit Enter or just white space. I've tried initializing a String called test as null and then setting scnr.nextLine() = test, and then checking if test is empty, but I didn't understand how to keep the rest of the program operating correctly when I did that. Scanner is very tricky to me. Please help!

```
        double mainNumber = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

            if (scnr.hasNextDouble() ){
                mainNumber = scnr.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(mainNumber);
                scnr.nextLine();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, please enter a number.\n");
                scnr.nextLine();
            }
```

Comment: The purpose of the program is that I would take the value stored in mainNumber and perform a calculation with it, and then that would be the end.

Comment: Define "number"... there are integers, decimals, hexadecimal/octal/exponential/.. formatted numbers, negative, complex, irrational numbers, etc..

Comment: I found at reference to ``Console#echo(boolean)`` in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java) and that (private) method turns off the user input echo. With that you can write your own input mask for the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use while-cycle and loop input as long as needed before user put a valid number.

This code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    double mainNumber = 0;
    boolean isValidNumber = false;

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    while (isValidNumber == false) {
        String line = scnr.nextLine();
        try {
            mainNumber = Double.valueOf(line);
            isValidNumber = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.print("Sorry, please enter a number.\n");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Main number is: " + mainNumber);
}
```

Having this sample output :

```
Enter a number: sdfgsgxb
Sorry, please enter a number.
xcvbxcvb
Sorry, please enter a number.
gsfdfgsdf
Sorry, please enter a number.
aearg
Sorry, please enter a number.
15.77
Main number is: 15.77
```

Comment: Good work, this is the answer I was preparing to submit. Alternatively, you can use a `do-while` loop with the same conditions, though that would prevent simple printing of an "error" message.

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess your code is in a while loop or something ? So that it keep asking until the user enter the right value.

Then you should (for convenience) use `String str = scnr.nextString()` instead of `nextDouble()` and analyze the string it returned.

You can use `str.trim()` to remove whitespaces (and then check if string is empty with `str.isEmpty()` ), and to check if it's a number you can use regexp ( [How to check that a string is parseable to a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543729/java-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-parsable-to-a-double) and any regex tutorial you can find ) or just use this regex: `str.matches("\\d+")` (returns true if str is a number, but no comma here).

Of course, don't forget to cast your String as double after: `Double.parseDouble( str.replace(",",".") );`. I hope the "replace" part is obvious ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following snippet to read one `double` value:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    double number = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Check the title: "How to prevent user from entering white space [...]"

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman, we've got `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String` if user entered only white spaces

Comment: your answer isn't wrong. but from the accepted answer I can see the question is poorly expressed...