# User input for creating objects

Tags: java, string, validation, input

I'm trying to code something to create a specific object if it matches the values that the user Inputs.

For example:

suppose I have Person class and Car class

```
public class Person
{
    private int x, y ,z;
    private String str;

    //Constructors etc
} 
public class Car
{
    private int x,y,z;
    private double doub;

    //Constructors etc
}
```

The user is asked to input 4 different values. The first three fields of Person and Car are the same but if the 4th value is a String or double, the program should create the matching object.

```
public class Input
{
     public static void main (String args[])
     {
         int x,y,z;
         ?? other; //how do i declare if its either a double or string

         Scanner input = new SCanner(System.in);
         x = input.nextInt();
         // y, z input
         other = input.??? //String or double

         //Create matching object
     }
}
```

How do i go about this?

Comment: Check if you can parse it as a double: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543729/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-parseable-to-a-double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `matches` to check if your input is double or a String for example :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String other = input.nextLine();
if (other.matches("\\d+\\.\\d+")) {
    //your input is double
    Double d = Double.parseDouble(other);
    System.out.println("double = " + d);

} else {
    //your intput is a Strings
    System.out.println(other);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object` for type and `instanceof` for checking

```
Scanner input = new SCanner(System.in);
x = input.nextInt();
// y, z input
string other = input.next();
Double d = null;
try {
  d = Double.parseDouble(other);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare other as string as a global and then check it if it double, you can save it in a double variable.

```
     Scanner input = new SCanner(System.in);
     x = input.nextInt();
     // y, z input
     string other = input.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `instanceof` keyword.

```
        System.out.println("Enter value");
        String userIn = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        try {
            if ((Double) Double.parseDouble(userIn) instanceof Double) {
                System.out.println("Double value is entered.");
                //Write your code here if it is double
            } else if (userIn instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("String is entered");
                //Write your code here if it is String
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("String is entered");
            //Write your code here if it is String
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a simple `String` to capture userinput, after that try to parse it into a `double`. If it can parse it it means that a valid double was entered and no exception will be thrown, in other words, it will execute the code in the `try` block. If it can't parse (throws an Exception) it will execute the code in the `catch` block.

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter something...");
    String userInput = kbd.next();
    Car car = null; // create empty Car object to be able to use it outside of the try/catch block
    Person person = null; // create empty Person object to be able to use it outside of the try/catch block

    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
        car = new Car();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        person = new Person();
    }

    // Ask user for new input and assign it to either Car or Person object as you develop your program...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to validate your input is to use a simple `try-catch`, for example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String other = input.nextLine();
Car car = null;
Person person = null;

try {
    // Is your input double
    Double d = Double.parseDouble(other);
    System.out.println("double = " + d);

    car = new Car();
    // ******* Write your statements to handle Car here *******

} catch (NumberFormatExaception nfe) {
    //your intput is a String
    System.out.println(other);

    person = new Person();
    // ******* Write your statements to handle Person here *******

}
```