# my app stops in emulator if one of my edit text box (contains Double value) is empty

Tags: java, android

After runnning my app in emulator to run kind of program it stopped if one of my edit text box is empty which were used in calculation with another edit text boxes to display result in text view boxes and so I must enter value and if I didn't enter it will stop the running program and one of those edit text (editText1) get it value from another activity page so I must go there to put number and I want to use this editText1 "sometimes" without going to that activity

```
  final EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

 double thick = Double.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
 double width = Double.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
 double length =  Double.valueOf(editText3.getText().toString());
 // this is the equation drive that values of previous double edit text
  double Weight = thick * width * length *0.9050 / 1000000 ;
  double Winder_output = thick * width * 0.905 * 60 / 1000000;
  // i displayed this results in Text View
  textView1.setText((String.format("%.2f",Weight)+" KG"));
  textView2.setText((String.format("%.2f", Winder_output)+"KG/HR"));
```

Comment: because empty string is not a double value

Comment: i used double value to easy use decimal number in cell.should i convert it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543729/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-parseable-to-a-double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "if" to check field is empty or not

```
 if (editText1.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enter value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return;
                }
```

Your code should look like this

```
      final EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

     if (editText1.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter thick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
                    }   
     if (editText2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter width",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
                    }
     if (editText3.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter length",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
                    } 

     double thick = Double.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
     double width = Double.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
     double length = Double.valueOf(editText3.getText().toString());
```

Comment: i tried to modify but i have error that i must make method called "trim"

Answer (score 0):

When edittext empty, it return string "", you should check

```
if(edittext.getText() != "")
```

then you can convert to double.

Comment: edit text in my case is double which cannot be defined with get tex